# STFDF vs. STARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, spatial, arima

I'm working on spatio-temporal anomaly analysis using R. 
I found a lot tutorials talking about converting data into STFDF( space-time full data frame) and use variogram method and then use stkrige function for prediction. And so I did. However, I found some research papers talking about STARIMA model , which is basically, ARIMA model but for space time data. 
Couldn't find any example how to implement it using R.
Does anyone have an idea how to implement it? 
Also, how does STARIMA is related to variogram? 
The reason why I'm asking is because when I used variogram and pull the plot for the time series of my data, I see outliers, and I couldn't find tutorials explains how to detect outliers with variogram. Anyone went through this topic before?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to Stata's documentation and find out what sort of specific statistical language and literature references were being used. Then you will have the terminology needed to search R documentation.

Comment: STARIMA was disced since 2006 but so far I couldn't find example how to implement it.. I used ARIMA model for time series prediction. I would like to add location

Comment: You should re-read my comment.

Comment: STARIMA was discussed since 2006 but so far I couldn't find examples show how to implement it. All research papers don't have much Theoretical details.. I used ARIMA model for time series prediction., and I would like to add location variable to my dataset and based on none-spatial variable, I do the prediction. This topic haven't been discussed as much as time series, and this is why I'm having problem to figure out  these terminology. I got confuse! And thought to share knowledge with all of you.

Comment: What about this? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/starma/starma.pdf